# Does anyone know if "SATA II" drives are compatible with a Dell SAS 5i/R?

Tags: sata, configuration, dell-poweredge, sas

I want to buy some cheaper HDs for our server (it will have practically zero HD access) but I plan to put them into a RAID 1 config, just for peace of mind. Our server is a second-hand **PowerEdge 860**, with a **SAS 5i/R** controller on it.

The existing drives (which came with the server) are Barracuda 7200.9's which are "**SATA II**" (i.e they've got 3Gb/s speeds and NCQ). That would answer my question except that Seagate made them to be 100% backwards compatible, too.

I'm concerned that newer, bigger disks, that may not be 1.5Gb/s backwards compatible, will not work with the SAS 5i/R controller.

Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed negotiation is part of the SATA initialization protocol.  Any controller worth it's weight properly implements this.  Some early VIA and SiS chipsets were known to fail at this, but I would expect better from the SAS 5i/R (LSI, I believe?)

Comment: Yep, rebadged LSI.

Comment: It is indeed an LSI (model #: UCS 51, I think).

Comment: Confirmed. Nautilus reports negotiation at 3.0Gb/s. Woo!

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on Dell's website ([link](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/RAID/SAS5iR/en/UG/HTML/index.htm)), SAS 5iR does support SATA, but doesn't explicitly say SATA I or II. Kyle Smith is right in terms of speed negotiation. *Newer* controllers *should* be able to handle speed negotiation. I'm willing to bet older controllers might require a jumper to enable it.

To answer your question: I don't think anyone knows for sure unless they've run your exact setup with the 5iR and the Seagate Barracuda 7200.9. If I were a gambler, I'd *personally* take the chance as SATA is fairly mature and commonplace these days.

According to Wikipedia (link), the section on "SATA 3 Gbit/s (Second generation)":

> Given the importance of backward
>   compatibility between SATA 1.5 Gbit/s
>   controllers and SATA 3 Gbit/s devices,
>   SATA 3 Gbit/s autonegotiation sequence
>   is designed to fall back to SATA 1.5
>   Gbit/s speed when in communication
>   with such devices. **In practice, some
>   older SATA controllers do not properly
>   implement SATA speed negotiation**.
>   Affected systems require the user to
>   set the SATA 3 Gbit/s peripherals to
>   1.5 Gbit/s mode, generally through the use of a jumper, however some drives
>   lack this jumper. Chipsets known to
>   have this fault include the VIA VT8237
>   and VT8237R southbridges, and the VIA
>   VT6420, VT6421A and VT6421L standalone
>   SATA controllers.[10] SiS's 760 and
>   964 chipsets also initially exhibited
>   this problem, though it can be
>   rectified with an updated SATA
>   controller ROM.[citation needed]

Seeing as you're using the SAS 5iR and don't have to worry about the VIA/SiS chipsets, I'd be willing to try it out. Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The specs on Dell's website DO say it supports 3Gb/s transfer... not sure if that means it includes the so-called "SATA II".

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a bit ambiguous, but considering the controller is relatively new, I'd bet on it and say it would work with the 7200.9 Barracudas.